# How to create DOM elements?

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I was going through simple HTML DOM parser and to create elements i found this syntax.

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

but the problem is that i have all my HTML data in a variable say $html_data that i have fetched using curl and applied HTML tidy.
When i try to use the syntax as :

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html($html_data); // 

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

What i think that it is not the correct syntax. Please correct if so.
The error is something --> Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\wamp..
This error seems like because i am using the wrong syntax (Not sure). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is using some kind of external library. There is no function called `file_get_html` in the PHP Standard Library.

It seems that you should first install the [PHP Simple HTTP Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). After that, just use `str_get_html` function as described [in the documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#frag_create_quick)

Comment: Ofcourse. sorry i forgot to mention the library i used from here [Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)